# Looking for power management software for Mac?

Tags: osx, battery

Use case 1: I'm in the office, on power cable, running several VMs, Photoshop, thousand of browser tabs.

Use case 2: I'm taking computer to a garden with no power cable.

I would like to switch power profile - sleep / disable all the apps - keep only essentials. Potentially disable Bluetooth and WiFi.

There is **Energy Saver** menu described here - http://is.oregonstate.edu/client-services/cn/tech-tips-using-cn/power-management/how-do-i-change-power-settings-my-apple - but it doesn't sleep apps automatically.

So to preserve battery life I quit most of the apps manually.

Is there an app for that?

---

EDIT / UPDATE / FOLLOW UP:

- at work I use magic trackpad and I drag&drop with 3 fingers, 4 fingers to switch desktops
- at home there is no magic trackpad and I would like to have different set of shortcuts

This of terms "preference profiles". I believe it can be performed via clever scripting of dotfiles but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) could be used to create macros to start or shutdown specific applications and make all sorts of other arrangements based on the WIFI you are currently connected to, a keyboard trigger, time of day or many more triggers.